# Can't increase spacing before section title

Tags: xetex, titlesec

I'm having troubles with increasing spacing between the header and section title. As suggested in `titlesec` package documentation, I added the following line to my preamble: `\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4em}{3em}`. If I understand correctly, it should provide 4em space before the section title and 3em space after it. However, it does not: that space before the title is clearly smaller, as you can see:

[image: image1]

I figured one ugly workaround: if I write `\vspace*{0em}` right before the `\section{...}`, the gap increases, however this time it's definitely *bigger* than 4em:

[image: image2]

The only way that could somehow solve my problem by far is to put there something like `\vspace*{-40em}`, but that's incredibly ugly and I would rather not do that by any means.

Google didn't help much. In fact, some results showed that people have issues with *decreasing* this size, but I didn't find much of a relevant info for my case.

The code I used for this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CH]{header}
\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1ex}{\uppercase}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4em}{3em}

\begin{document}
    %\vspace*{0pt}
    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The behavior is perfectly normal for a section title that starts a new page. The gap you see from the header rule and the title is the "headsep". So, if you add `\vspace*{0pt}` you get 4em *plus* the headsep.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `\vspace*{-40em}`? -4 seems more reasonable.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for quick reply! Indeed, I forgot about the headsep when I was writing this example. So what would be the best way to work this around? I could write something like ``\vspace*{-\headsep}`` before every section, but it looks ugly to me—or is this perfectly fine?

Comment: @Ryan I actually meant -40pt, my mistake. Thanks for notice.

Comment: @Kona-chan The problem is only in sections that start a new page. I really can't understand why you need them to stay so low.

Comment: @egreg Well, specifications of my qualifying work dictate that distance between the header and section title must be exactly 4 lines. I'm probably being wrong here assuming that's equal 4em, but it seemed right so far. Also, it is said that every section must start with a new page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible approximation to the specifications (as usual made by people that show little knowledge of typography, as testified by the 14pt size) is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,headsep=\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{header}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\sectionfix}{\newpage\vspace*{3\baselineskip}\nointerlineskip}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1ex}{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{3em}

\preto{\section}{\sectionfix} % sections start a new page

\begin{document}
    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Lorem ipsum}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Notice that `\MakeUppercase` is better than `\uppercase`; the package `xunicode` is loaded automatically by `fontspec`, while `xltxtra` is not required nor recommended as it used to be (but you *can* load it if you want).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful, I managed to somehow modify your code so it would work with `\doublespacing`—my apologies for not making it clear I have to use double spacing to begin with. Looks like it will have to do with some precisious font manipulation. At least I no longer need to write `\vspace*{0em}` every time.

Comment: @Kona-chan You mean that you're requested to have 14pt font size *and* double spacing? That's simply crazy. :(

Comment: Yeah, our specs give me a headache.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion between @Kona-chan and @egreg, especially the rhetorical:

> I could write something like `\vspace*{-\headsep}` before every section, but it looks ugly to me—or is this perfectly fine?

I think what you may want to do is something like `\renewcommand{\headsep}{1pt}` after `\begin{document}`. That will alter all the sections that start a new page.

I agree with @egreg that it seems unattractive. But specs are specs.

Comment: But it would affect the pages that doesn't contain new section as well, effectively pushing _all_ text up, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah...thought that was what you wanted...everything jutting up against the header. Guess not. @egreg's answer seems better.